# Generating random number for specific column in table

Tags: linux, awk, sed

How can I generate a random numbers for the values in a required column?

for example: 
I have the following data and I want to generate random number for column 3.

```
Col1                  Col2,  Col3,     Col4, col5, col 6
2015-04-05 12:00:00Z, Rob-1, 47176121, 6,    3,    0.0
2015-04-05 12:00:00Z, Rob-2, 47176121, 6,    4,    0.0
2015-04-05 12:00:00Z, Rob-3, 37856233, 4,     ,    0.0
2015-04-05 12:00:00Z, Rob-4, 37856233, 5,     ,    0.0
2015-04-05 12:00:00Z, Rob-4, 4152121,  6,    0,    0.0
2015-04-05 12:00:00Z, Rob-5, 41452121, 16,    ,    0.0
2015-04-05 12:00:00Z, Rob-6, 41452121, 6,    0,    0.0
```

I have used `awk '!a[$0]{do{x=int(rand()*100000000);a[$0]=x}while(b[x])}{print $0,a[$0]}' file`

but that doesn't seem to work.

Edited
The expected output should be like:-

```
Col1                  Col2,  Col3,     Col4, col5, col 6
2015-04-05 12:00:00Z, Rob-1, 111, 6,    3,    0.0
2015-04-05 12:00:00Z, Rob-2, 111, 6,    4,    0.0
2015-04-05 12:00:00Z, Rob-3, 567, 4,     ,    0.0
2015-04-05 12:00:00Z, Rob-4, 567, 5,     ,    0.0
2015-04-05 12:00:00Z, Rob-4, 90009,  6,    0,    0.0
2015-04-05 12:00:00Z, Rob-5, 90009, 16,    ,    0.0
2015-04-05 12:00:00Z, Rob-6, 90009, 6,    0,    0.0
```

when the new values in column 3 are randomly generated numbers the coincides with the values that was there before, so if the value appeared more than once, it will have the same random number being consistent

Comment: In awk terms, what's the [field separator](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Field-Separators)?

Comment: It would be the comma.

Comment: What about that "doesn't work"? What is your output? What *should* the output be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you're just not replacing the 3rd field

```
awk -F", " -v OFS=", " 'NR > 1 {$3 = int(rand()*100000000)} {print}' file
```

Note that awk (gawk anyway) generates the same sequence of pseudo-random numbers every time. If you don't want that, add `BEGIN {srand()}` ([ref](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Numeric-Functions.html))

---

Oh, so you want to replace each value in $3 keyed on that value. OK:

```
awk -F", " -v OFS=", " '
    NR > 1 {$3 = ($3 in r ? r[$3] : r[$3]=int(rand()*100000000))} 
    {print}
' file
```

```
Col1                  Col2,  Col3,     Col4, col5, col 6
2015-04-05 12:00:00Z, Rob-1, 23778751, 6,    3,    0.0
2015-04-05 12:00:00Z, Rob-2, 23778751, 6,    4,    0.0
2015-04-05 12:00:00Z, Rob-3, 29106573, 4,     ,    0.0
2015-04-05 12:00:00Z, Rob-4, 29106573, 5,     ,    0.0
2015-04-05 12:00:00Z, Rob-4, 84581385,  6,    0,    0.0
2015-04-05 12:00:00Z, Rob-5, 15220829, 16,    ,    0.0
2015-04-05 12:00:00Z, Rob-6, 15220829, 6,    0,    0.0
```

Comment: this above example is adding ", , 23778751" at the end of each line instead of replacing the column 3 value

Comment: I'm just going by the sample text you gave. Are there spaces after the comma or not?

Comment: There isn't. Also how would I adjust the command so that it doesn't miss the first column?

Comment: Like this: `awk -F, -v OFS=, '...'`